# uwsgi-nginx in docker not works

Tags: docker, nginx, uwsgi

I have Dockerfile like:

```
FROM python:3.6.5-jessie
MAINTAINER twitter myname

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN git clone https://github.com/hongmingu/requirements
RUN pip install -r /requirements/requirements_django.txt
RUN apt-get install -y vim

RUN mkdir -p /uwsgi_log

RUN git clone https://github.com/hongmingu/smaple_django

RUN apt-get install -y nginx

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./uwsgi.ini /uwsgi.ini # it runs in daemonized mode
# These files are just setting files. nginx get request at port 8000 and uwsgi runs django project.

RUN uwsgi --ini /uwsgi.ini

RUN service nginx restart

CMD ["python3"]
```

I think these 2 lines not work:

```
RUN uwsgi --ini /uwsgi.ini
RUN service nginx restart
```

Because When I build it and run it with linux command: `sudo docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8000 hongmingu/smaple:0.1 /bin/bash` my 127.0.0.1:8080 does not work. But, When I attach container and type command manually like, `uwsgi --ini /uwsgi.ini` and `service nginx restart`, It works well.

So, Is it impossible to run uwsgi, nginx in Dockerfile?

I want to do it so that I hope I don't need to run uwsgi and nginx manually.

Where did I make fault? Is there any good way to do this?

This docker image(hongmingu/smaple:0.1) is here: https://cloud.docker.com/u/hongmingu/repository/docker/hongmingu/smaple

Comment: You should broadly assume that commands like `service` don’t run in Docker.  It certainly makes no sense to attempt to restart a service in a Dockerfile since a Docker image doesn’t contain any running processes, only filesystem content.  Consider breaking this into two separate images, one process each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the `RUN` instruction

> The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of
>   the current image and commit the results

It's used to build your image, it is not `docker run` which executes the command in the container.

The solutions involves to execute those 2 lines in the CMD or ENTRYPOINT with a shell script. uwsgi has also to be daemonized. Checkout this image https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-docker